# Split a file into two files at a given line

Tags: unix

I'm looking for a way in unix to split a file into two files at a given line number.

`split -l 100 file_name` is close to what I'm looking for, but this command creates multiple files, each of 100 lines. I'm looking for a command to split a file into two files at a given line number. Is there a way to do this in unix?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A bit tighter solution:

```
(head -100 > f1.txt; cat > f2.txt) < input.txt
```

Comment: Nice solution. No counting with `wc` before and the input file is still processed only once, like with the `awk` solution.

Comment: There is a slight chance that `head` will read more than just 100 lines in order to find the first 100 lines to output to `f1.txt`; those extra bytes will not be seen by `cat`.

Comment: This is so damn slow

Answer (score 14):

Use `awk`, so that you need to make just one pass through the input file. The following
assumes you want the first 122 lines in the first file, and the remainder in the second.

```
awk 'NR < 123 { print >> "top_file"; next } {print >> "bottom_file" }' file_name
```

Comment: This deserves a thumbs up. if you want to split a file from X to Y, this is the easiest.

Comment: This is the easiest solution to understand. Worked like a charm...and makes me think I should brush the dust off of my O'Reilly Sed & Awk book I have had since 1999 or so, the sed section is well-read, awk section not so much.

Comment: This is better than the excepted solution for the reason @chepner metioned in the comments. You will loose characters in the 'f2.txt' file. This solution is accurate and efficient. awk ftw.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `head` and `tail` to get both parts:

```
head -n K file_name > top_file
tail -n L file_name > bottom_file
```

where `K` is the line number, and `L` is number of lines from the bottom (total number of lines - `K`).

(you can get the total number of lines using `wc -l file_name`).

Comment: considering that I was splitting on a line with a specific content (found with `egrep -n xxx filename`), this was the approach I took.  in zsh and bash `let "n = totallines - K"` did the trick.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `csplit` (if available) to do it:

```
csplit file N+1
```

will split the file into two pieces, one piece up to (and including) line number `N` and the other piece from line number `N+1` up to the last line.
If you want to split up to (but not including) line number `N`:

```
csplit file N
```

Comment: That is great! Thanks, it solved the problem perfectly for me.

Comment: Best performance for splitting 20GB file into pieces.

Comment: @dr0i - no wonder, `csplit` is optimized for this job.

Comment: Splitting a 200M-lines-file I got "memory exhausted" using a csplit dated back to 2008. Using csplit dated to 2011 it works :)

Answer (score 4):

Both `head` and `tail` have options to produce lines from the "other" end of the file than they otherwise would. So you have these two options:

```
head -n 100 source.txt > file1.txt
head -n -100 source.txt > file2.txt
```

or (where NNN is 100 less than the output of `wc -l source.txt`):

```
tail -n +NNN source.txt > file1.txt
tail -n NNN source.txt > file.txt
```

You can read the manual pages for your versions of `head` and `tail` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'wc', 'dc', 'head' and 'tail'. I.e.

```
unix> wc -l foo
545 /tmp/foo
unix> dc -e '545 100 - p'
445
unix> head -n 100 foo > filea
unix> tail -n 445 foo > fileb
```

For ease of use, you can turn above into a shell script.